# Restore textarea value on cancel

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular 5 project i have text area, where i bind some value (comments editor)  with save/cancel buttons, i want restore old text area value when user click 'cancel' button.

Template:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="comment.text"></textarea>

<button (click)="cancelEdit(comment.text)">Cancel</button>
```

Component:

```
oldCommentValue: string;

cancelEdit(comment) {
  comment = this.oldCommentValue;
}
```

But this does not restore old value. What i did wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Typescript or Angular, but have you tried `comment.text = this.oldCommentValue`? Simply overriding the whole object will not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set this value to your local variable in this case

```
this.comment.text = this.oldCommentValue;
```

not

```
comment = this.oldCommentValue;
```